# LibreOffice; Cannot dock Navigator or Styles Panel

Tags: macos, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am posting to this community since there are other questions relating to LibreOffice. Please let me know if there is a more relevant community.

I managed to undock the Navigator and Styles panels, but I cannot dock them again.

I am running LO6 (tried 6.1 & 6.2) on a Macintosh, and I think some of the keyboard controls don’t work the same way.

I have tried Ctrl Double Click as well as Cmd Double Click as well as just about every other keyboard combination. The alternative of dragging the pane to the edge doesn’t work either.

Is there a trick I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

For the standard sidebar, the settings button in the top right gives the option to dock/undock the sidebar.

For the separate navigator (not the one in the sidebar), Ctrl + Double Click does work, but it's extremely finicky on my system (Ubuntu with KDE), so perhaps the problem is the same on Mac OS. Try it on one of the dividers between icons, or on the thin blank border, rather than large open blank sections. This works on the normal sidebar as well.